# Get refreshToken property in Android with Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working in a project, which uses Firebase Auth (with tenant_ids). After the login is successful, I need to get access to the idToken, as well as the refreshToken properties, which should be part of the FirebaseUser object.

In the JS Firebase library the refreshToken is available:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

In the Swift Firebase library, the refreshToken is available as well in the User object:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User

However in the Kotlin/Java Firebase library, there's no access to the refreshToken property from the FirebaseUser object:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser

In the kotlin library I only get access to the idToken, however not to the refreshToken as in JS and Swift

So, Is there any way to get access to the refreshToken property for the Android libraries?

Comment: Without reaching into private properties and poking around the instances of `CredentialsProvider`, I don't think there's a public API surface for that. This is the source code for the [Android SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk) (each module in the SDK contains a `/src/main/java/...` and a `/ktx/src/main/kotlin/...`)